# Sort Multidimensional Array using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My PHP array ($array) is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [channels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 5
                    [id] => 11
                    [name] => AFK
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 1
                    [id] => 22
                    [name] => ARK
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 2
                    [id] => 33
                    [name] => ESO
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 4
                    [id] => 44
                    [name] => semi-afk
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 0
                    [id] => 55
                    [name] => SPACE
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [position] => 3
                    [id] => 66
                    [name] => Tanks & Ships
                )
        )

    [instant_invite] => 
    [id] => 123
    [members] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => Chartographer
                    [status] => online
                    [nick] => Chaz Rambone
                    [avatar_url] => https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png
                    [avatar] => 
                    [discriminator] => 3270
                    [id] => 124
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => Chukers
                    [status] => online
                    [mute] => 
                    [suppress] => 
                    [deaf] => 
                    [channel_id] => 789
                    [game] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => The Elder Scrolls Online
                        )

                    [avatar_url] => https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/1.png
                    [avatar] => 
                    [self_deaf] => 
                    [discriminator] => 9851
                    [self_mute] => 
                    [id] => 456
                )
        )

    [name] => TEST
)
```

I want to sort by "position" starting at 0 and ASC.

I tried some of the examples found here but not getting it yet. Usort and a few others are not working for me. Sure it's syntax but not sure

```
if  ($array->channels) {
    usort($array->channels, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->position > $b->position ? 1 : -1;
 });
```

Comment: `$a['position'], $b['position']`. `$a` and `$b` are arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you're trying to use object notation, but you're referencing an array. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) has very helpful examples.

```
usort($array['channels'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] > $b['position'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

[See this fiddle example.](https://3v4l.org/2F4TH)